# How to set type of dataset when applying transformations and how to implement transformations without using spark.sql.functions._?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner for Scala and have been working on the following problem:

Example dataset named as `given_dataset` with player number and points scored

```
  |player_no|   |points|
       1          25.0
       1          20.0
       1          21.0
       2          15.0
       2          18.0
       3          24.0
       3          25.0
       3          29.0
```

Problem 1:
I have a dataset and need to calculate total points scored, average points per game, and number of games played. **I am unable to explicitly set the data type to "double", "int", "float", when I apply the transformations.** (Perhaps this is because they are untyped transformations?) **Would anyone be able to help on this and correct my error?**

**No data type specified (but code is able to run)**

```
val total_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").sum("points").orderBy("player_no")
val games_played_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").count().orderBy("player_no")
val avg_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").avg("points").orderBy("player_no")
```

Please note that I would like to retain the player number as I plan to merge total_points_dataset, games_played_dataset, and avg_points_dataset together.

**Data type specified, but code crashes!**

```
val total_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").sum("points").as[Double].orderBy("player_no")
val games_played_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").count().as[Int].orderBy("player_no")
val avg_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").avg("points").as[Double].orderBy("player_no")
```

Problem 2:
I would like to implement the above without using the library `spark.sql.functions` e.g. through functions such as map, groupByKey etc. If possible, could anyone provide an example for this and point me towards the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{FloatType, IntegerType, StructType}` then you have to cast it either at the time of reading or using `as[(Int, Double)]` in the dataset. Below is the example while reading from CSV file for your dataset:

```
/** A function that splits a line of input into (player_no, points) tuples. */
def parseLine(line: String): (Int, Float) = {
    // Split by commas
    val fields = line.split(",")
    // Extract the player_no and points fields, and convert to integer & float
    val player_no = fields(0).toInt
    val points = fields(1).toFloat
    // Create a tuple that is our result.
    (player_no, points)
}
```

And then read as below:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "StackOverflow75354293")
val lines = sc.textFile("data/stackoverflowdata-noheader.csv")
val dataset = lines.map(parseLine)
val total_points_dataset2 = dataset.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
val total_points_dataset2_sorted = total_points_dataset2.sortByKey(ascending = true)
total_points_dataset2_sorted.foreach(println)
val games_played_dataset2 = dataset.countByKey().toList.sorted
games_played_dataset2.foreach(println)
val avg_points_dataset2 =
  dataset
    .mapValues(x => (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
    .mapValues(x => x._1 / x._2)
    .sortByKey(ascending = true)
avg_points_dataset2.collect().foreach(println)
```

I locally tried running both ways and both are working fine, we can check the below output also:

```
(3,78.0)
(1,66.0)
(2,33.0)

(1,3)
(2,2)
(3,3)

(1,22.0)
(2,16.5)
(3,26.0)
```

For details you can see it on [mysql page](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/SparkScalaCourse/blob/abc70b2924d1af633ee5c58c255a32a93944de63/src/main/scala/com/sundogsoftware/spark/StackOverflow75354293.scala)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "Problem 1" try

```
val total_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").sum("points").as[(Int, Double)].orderBy("player_no")
val games_played_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").count().as[(Int, Long)].orderBy("player_no")
val avg_points_dataset = given_dataset.groupBy($"player_no").avg("points").as[(Int, Double)].orderBy("player_no")
```